# JavaScript - Searching for a char in string using indexOf()

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, indexof

When verifying that character is NOT in string, is it both the same when using `if(string.indexOf("x") < 0) { ... }` or `if(string.indexOf("x") == -1) { ... }`?

Could there be some circumstances when `string.indexOf("x")` would be `-2` or lower?

Thank you for sharing your experiences.

Comment: No, It will always be `-1` if sub string not found in the string. There is no chance to return values below that.

Comment: The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string. This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could there be some circumstances when string.indexOf("x") would be -2 or lower?

No. It cannot. Index is negative (-1) only when there is no match.

> When verifying that character is NOT in string, is it both the same when using 
>   if(string.indexOf("x") < 0) { ... } or if(string.indexOf("x") == -1) { ... }

Of course they are the same because `-1<0`.

Answer (score 2):

According to `indexOf()` [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), it can return a value: `-1` (if substring not found) and from `0` up to `string.length - 1` (indicating the match position).

---

A better approach is to use the ECMAScript 6 [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) `includes()`:

```
var string = 'x-files';

string.includes('x'); // prints true
```

Answer (score 1):

They are the same:

> "The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present."

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)